# Console log flooded with "VMware Fusion Start Menu ... : assertion failed: ..."

Tags: macos, vmware, logs, console

I get tons of messages of this style in my console log:

```
08.12.14 11:03:41,045 VMware Fusion Start Menu[444]: assertion failed: 14B25: libxpc.dylib + 40320 [9437C02E-A07B-38C8-91CB-299FAA63083D]: 0x13
```

The effect started after updating OS X from Mavericks to Yosemite. Updating to Yosemite 10.10.1 did not help.

I have installed VMWare Fusion 6.05 which should be compatible to Yosemite and the effect happens also when Fusion is NOT running.

The problem is hard to investigate as the string appears in many posted logs that discuss other topics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After multiple attempts to solve this, I finally found the solution in a side note of a [VMWare community thread](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/493875):

Start Fusion, select one of your VMs (no matter which one) and change the virtual machine settings like this:
Virtual machine -> Settings -> Application Menu -> "Show only when machine is running"

After I did this the messages stopped immediately. I could even switch back to the default setting of "Always" and the messages did not reappear.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, but after I performed the VMware Free upgrade the issue was resolved.